# I am getting issue with drupal VM while running blt vm command on my mac terminal getting issue

Tags: drupal, ansible

> TASK [geerlingguy.composer : Add GitHub OAuth token for Composer (if configured).] ***
> skipping: [novartis-dolphin]
>
> TASK [geerlingguy.composer : include_tasks] ************************************
> included: /Users/challsaa/novartis-dolphin/vendor/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/provisioning/roles/geerlingguy.composer/tasks/global-require.yml for novartis-dolphin
>
> TASK [geerlingguy.composer : Install configured globally-required packages.] ***
> failed: [novartis-dolphin] (item={'name': 'hirak/prestissimo', 'release': '^0.3'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/composer", "global", "require", "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3", "--no-progress"], "delta": "0:00:00.395660", "end": "2020-11-10 08:41:28.064471", "item": {"name": "hirak/prestissimo", "release": "^0.3"}, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-11-10 08:41:27.668811", "stderr": "Changed current directory to /home/vagrant/.composer\n\n \n [InvalidArgumentException] \n Package hirak/prestissimo at version ^0.3 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version \n \n\nrequire [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...", "stderr_lines": ["Changed current directory to /home/vagrant/.composer", "", " ", " [InvalidArgumentException] ", " Package hirak/prestissimo at version ^0.3 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version ", " ", "", "require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []..."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
>
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
> novartis-dolphin : ok=108 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=109 rescued=0 ignored=1
>
> Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
> visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

Comment: What is this?please edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Composer v2 conflicts with `hirak/prestissimo`. Please see https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/2099.

The maintainer is preparing a `v6.0.2` in https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/2101 release but meanwhile you can downgrade your composer to v1 to get around this issue: `composer self-update --1`